# Querying multiple SQL tables in a single statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables on my database.

One called **room** and another is called **room_booking**.

Both room and room booking have the same column **room_id**.

I've drafted the following SQL query that checks for rooms with a specific date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id FROM `room_booking` WHERE date_booked='$date'";
```

But now I need to use the list of id's to access the info respective rooms in room_booking. The fields I am interested in are **name** and **room_size**.

How can I achieve this? Would I require a joint SQL statement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should [**Join**](http://mysqljoin.com/) both tables for getting results.

Try below

```
SELECT  r.roomid,r.room, r.room_size,date_booked 
FROM room  as r left  JOIN room_booking  as rb ON r.room_id=rb.room_id 
WHERE date_booked='$date'
```

Comment: Two questions @Teez: **1)** How do I echo the rows from each table? Do I still use `$row['room_id']` (which is in both tables) for example and `$row['date_booked']` (which is in the room_booking table) **2)** Will `WHERE date_booked<>'$date'` work as well if dates are in the format '2012-01-01'?

Comment: @methuselah : 1)Yes you have to  use $row['room_id'] and $row['date_booked'] but they should be specified in select clause.2) Yes it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to use the `JOIN` statement as follows

```
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT room, room_size FROM room JOIN `room_booking` ON room.room_id=`room_booking`.room_id WHERE date_booked='$date' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing wrong query you can change it as like

```
SELECT room_id FROM `room_booking` as rb,room as r WHERE date_booked='$date' and r.room_id=rb.room_id
```

When you are getting data from multiple tables if you are not using joins it will give you cartison product of the data.